# CoordinatorLayout & RelativeLayout screen space difference

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Why extra space in bottoms gets considered in screen calculation when i use `CoordinatorLayout` and not when i use `RelativeLayout`.

[image: with CoordinatorLayout]  [image: with RelativeLayout]

see the blue part which is been added in Coordinator layout at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity.controller.MainActivityNew">


      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

           <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <FrameLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

i am adding fragments to the `FrameLayout` which has FAB. in case of `CoordinatorLayout` my FAB button gets hidden under navigation menu button.

what could be possible solution to this. or why this extra space gets added to screen layout and how to avoid this extra bottom space.?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

In your Toolbar you have added app:layout_scrollFlags

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Remove that scrollFlags in Toolbar

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

**There is no need to use layout_below in CoordinatorLayout** 
Avoid to use layout_below.
Here I have added complete code check this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Only use this is not sufficient for answer do brief description what you have used in your answer. Why and what changes you have made. So he can learn through your answer.

Comment: Ok sorry for that :) @jaydroider

Comment: i need FAB in my Fragment. why would i put this in activity_main? also it would still go out of the screen as you can see the height acquired by the Layout is off the screen so gravity param wont work

Comment: @jaydroider it would be enough if you could just explain the behavior of height

Comment: You should remove   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" from your Toolbar @ndeokar . That's why the screen expanding . Remove it

Comment: You no need to call the layout_below in CoordinatorLayout remove it too @ndeokar

Comment: If you don't need Fab just remove it. See the code now. @ndeokar

Comment: @MathaN Tell this to ndeokar the Question owner not me and put this things in your answer. As you always have rights to edit your answer.

Comment: Changed :) sorry again :) @jaydroider

Comment: so sorry was out... trying now

Comment: that didint work @MathaN and  need layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" flags as they would scroll the toolbar up when i scroll my fragment.